# Streamplot error: Cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to use the streamplot function to plot a velocity field but for some reason it is failing. Here is an original SO post about the function with an example: [how to plot streamlines , when i know u and v components of velocity(numpy 2d arrays), using a plotting program in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296617/how-to-plot-a-streamlines-when-i-know-u-and-v-components-of-velocitynumpy-2d). The example works fine for me; however, I tried to modify the values to simplify the function and imitate initial conditions and now it no longer works.

Here's my "simplified" code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from streamplot import streamplot

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 2, 10)
u = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))
v = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))
u[:,len(y)-1]=1
speed = np.sqrt(u*u + v*v)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
streamplot(x, y, u, v,density=1, INTEGRATOR='RK4', color='b')
plt.subplot(122)
streamplot(x, y, u, v, density=(1,1), INTEGRATOR='RK4', color=u,
           linewidth=5*speed/speed.max())
plt.show()
```

Any recommendations or help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO!.  For us to help you best, you need to help us by giving use enough information in your question.  _how_ does it no longer work?  Did it give you any errors (if so please paste in the _whole_ error)?

Comment: Have you tried using streamplot from matplotlib?  Instead of importing streamplot from streamplot, try using `plt.streamplot`

Comment: Your v-vector is 0 and you u-vector is 0 except for the last column, what kind of 'stream' would you expect from this? Are you sure those values are correct?

Comment: tcaswell: Because there are zeros in the arrays, I get an error, whereas in the example from SO the arrays are all non-zero, and there is no error.

Comment: Rutger: Yes, those are correct. I am trying to get this working so I can use it to make an animation of a velocity field over time. The initial conditions involve zero; however, as time progresses most of the field becomes nonzero. I have omitted the rest of the code for simplification.

Comment: Here is the quiver plot of the final field: [link](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/b181o0fg/Selection_047.png) to give you a better idea.

Comment: askewchan: I have tried using plt.streamplot, but I have the same problem. It seems that these streamplot functions don't work well with zeros. I find this odd given that quiver has no problem with it. Could there be a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the density of your `(x,y)` grid (you've switched `x` and `y` in your initialization of `u` and `v`, by the way) is less than the density of the `streamplot` grid.  When you set `density=1` or `(1,1)` (they should be equivalent) then "the domain is divided into a 25x25 grid".  I think that means that there is some smoothing going on if your data is nonzero in a slim enough region compared to the density of either the streamplot or your x-y grid.  I couldn't get it to work by increasing those densities (`density` or the `linspace` spacing). but if you make *two* columns nonzero at the edge, it seems to work fine.

Seems like the streamplot function is not very robust for these cases and perhaps you should submit a bug.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 2, 10)
u = np.zeros((y.size, x.size))
v = np.zeros((y.size, x.size))
u[:,-2:] = 1
speed = np.sqrt(u*u + v*v)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.streamplot(x, y, u, v,density=1, color='b')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.streamplot(x, y, u, v, density=(1,1), color=u, linewidth=5*speed/speed.max())
plt.show()
```

Comment: askewchan: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. That worked out perfectly (see [here](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/0icgbhkp/Selection_001.png) for results). Thanks Again!

Comment: @William My pleasure, thanks for showing the result: but that link doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Try this [one](http://i.imgur.com/KLRslKu.png) or this [one](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/715/selection001gc.png). For anyone that's interested, the problem is lid-driven cavity flow. There is fluid in a box and the top is moving at a constant velocity (causing the vortices in the middle). Pressure is plotted as a contour in the back.

Comment: @William They all work now, including the original.  Very cool!