# Plotting stream traces in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Using `with vector` in `gnuplot`, I can plot nice vector fields of data sets consisting of four columns. What are my options, if, instead of a velocity vector field, I want to plot stream traces? Does `gnuplot` have a built-in functionality to accomplish this?

Of course I know that I can externally calculate the stream traces based on the vector field, but I would like to have it automated in Gnuplot. How to approach this (if it is possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, gnuplot doesn't have that ability.  There's really a huge difference in processing between plotting a vector-field and plotting streamlines.  The vector field only depends on the local point whereas the streamlines need to be calculated from the previous data -- Something which gnuplot doesn't do.

Comment: I was afraid for this answer. I will wait a bit for other answer before I accept. Thanks.

Comment: @Bernhard -- Yeah, it's a bit of a bummer.  Good luck.

Comment: using other program to finish this task line Python or TVTK. In fact the most import point in your point is how your data is organized and you want to show it. For example you can refer this (url)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296617/how-to-plot-a-streamlines-when-i-know-u-and-v-components-of-velocitynumpy-2d]